# How to check if a form is already opened?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I open `JFrame` forms from a `JMenuBar` using the following code:

```
    FrmTestFrom frm = new FrmTestFrom();
    frm.setVisible(true);
```

The issue is that **I do not want the same form to open again** if the user clicks the same menu item. If the form is already open. I would like the already opened form to get focused instead of opening a new one.

Comment: *"I open `JFrame` forms.."* See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, need to change constructor to

```
public static FrmTest getObj() {
    if (obj == null) {
        obj = new FrmTest();
    }
    
    return obj;
}
```

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iFZplhRnmW8&ab_channel=raksrahul